# Getting null before each line while scanning txt file

Tags: java

I'm having a problem reading a txt file and find a word/pattern using java's scanner.util. 
Currently testing out the reading and I'm getting null infront of each line. After that problem, I'm still not sure how to search for the pattern/word in the txt file. I also have to display the line which contains the pattern/word.

```
public class SearchPattern {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      String pattern;
      String filename;
      String[] text = new String[10];
      System.out.println("Enter the filename");
      filename = s.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Enter the pattern you'd like to search");
      pattern = s.nextLine();
      // Print out each line that contains pattern
      // may need an array to store StringS of lines with word
      try{
         s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
         int x = 0;
         while (s.hasNext()) {
            text[x] += s.next();
            x++;
         }
      }
      finally {
         if (s != null) {
            s.close();
         }
      }
      text[0] = "test";
      System.out.println(text[0]);
      for(String txt : text){
         System.out.println(txt);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename)));
        int x = 0;
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            text[x] += s.next();
            x++;
        }
```

What you are doing here, is iterating over your array in a way I guess you are not trying to do.

Right now, for every x position in your array, you are writing

```
text[x] = text[x] + s.next();
```

But what you probably want to do is to give every position in your array the value of the next value of the scanner. In code

```
text[x] = s.next();
```

This could also be written as

```
        for((int x = 0; s.hasNext(); x++)
            text[x] = s.next();
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You do:

```
text[x] += s.next();
```

That means: `text[x]` is `null` than you append `s.next()`

Replace it with:

```
text[x] = s.next();
```

Comment: You answered and solved my problem first, but the other guy answered more in detail which helped me further understand. Thank you both very much and sorry to bother you with such a noob question.